# How to include CouchDB _users DB properties into another DB's view?

Tags: couchdb

I am adding more user profile information to the _users DB in CouchDB. This includes things like first name, last name, etc. This works fine and I'm able to store additional profile information.

How do I get that profile information to be linked in (joined) from another DB's view map function? That is, each document has an author or user field which records the user that created the document. How do I get other profile information about the user included in the view created for this DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to join documents across different databases. The closest thing you can have to that is creating copies of user profile information inside your other database, and perhaps using replication to keep that information synchronized.

I'm not sure if there are any plans to have special databases like _users behave differently, but I'm sure there are enough use-cases to make it a worthwhile endeavor. However, there is no mention of this (as far as I've seen) in the Wiki or anywhere else of note.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's the conclusion I came to by reviewing the Wiki and other documentation, but it seems like such a common use case, that I thought I had overlooked something.